# What is the Path to root folder? Vimeo API

Tags: php, api, path, root, vimeo

[image]

Im trying to run this Vimeo API in my PHP, and these are the error messages:

**Warning: require(D:\XAMPP\htdocs\MyVimeo/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\XAMPP\htdocs\MyVimeo\testing.php on line 9**

**Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'D:\XAMPP\htdocs\MyVimeo/autoload.php' (include_path='D:\XAMPP\php\PEAR') in D:\XAMPP\htdocs\MyVimeo\testing.php on line 9**

And my question is, what is the path to the root folder? This is my source code that I'm trying to run:

```
<?php
      require 'D:\XAMPP\htdocs\MyVimeo/autoload.php';
      use Vimeo\Vimeo;
      $client = new Vimeo("xxx","xxx","xxx");

      $url="https://api.vimeo.com/videos/xxx";
      $ch=curl_init();
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
      echo curl_exec($ch);
      curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to put `require 'vendor/autoload.php';` and not change to actual path.

What you are missing is running `composer install` command in your root directory from the terminal

**According to the documentation**

**With Composer, in the root directory of your project.**

```
composer require vimeo/vimeo-api
```

Please note that this library requires at least PHP 7.1 installed. If you are on PHP 5.6, or PHP 7.0, please use install the package with the following:

```
composer require vimeo/vimeo-api ^2.0
```

Then once you do that, you can use

```
require "vendor/autoload.php";
```

Comment: hi there thank you so much for the reply, I will replace to require 'vendor/autoload.php';  but I have installed composer, its still not working

Comment: did you run `composer install` @MLSiew

Comment: it shows this message:Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
25 packages you are using are looking for funding.
Use the `composer fund` command to find out more!

Comment: are you using this sdk https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.php

Comment: @MLSiew, I have updated the answer. It works in my system. Before doing so, delete the existing directories that you have created for this package `(MyVimeo)`

Comment: Also, you should not use  absolute path`require 'D:\XAMPP\htdocs\MyVimeo/autoload.php';`. Use a relative one `require MyVimeo/autoload.php` if that contains the `vendor` folder

Comment: Okay noted Sir. Do you mind sharing what web server you use? Because I'm using XAMPP, it should be fine right?

Comment: Yes xampp should be fine. Although I am using nginx on mac

Comment: hi there my friend Im facing another problem now. Appreciate if you can take a look at it and share some of your thoughts. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63574280/how-to-call-a-vimeo-api-in-php?noredirect=1#comment112419777_63574280