# How to call a Vimeo API in php?

Tags: php, api, curl, vimeo

I am trying to run this API(https://developer.vimeo.com/api/reference/videos#get_video). My goal is to call the API and print out the result, because after I run the the code, nothing is printed from the API call. Appreciate if anyone can help me. Thanks :

FYI, these are my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <?php
      require ("vendor/autoload.php");
  use Vimeo\Vimeo;
  $client = new Vimeo("{client_id}", "{client_secret}", "{access_token}");

   $video_id ="447518879";
   $response = $client->request("/videos/$video_id");
   //var_dump($response['body']);

   if($response['status'] === 200){
     echo json_encode($response['body']['message']);
   }
  else {
      echo json_encode($response['body']['error']);
  }

       ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You init the Vimeo client but don't use it to make requests. Don't use cURL but the client, more info at https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.php#make-requests. Also, using https://developer.vimeo.com/api/reference/videos#get_video returns `"error": "The requested video couldn't be found."` when looking for video #447518879

Comment: you already got the library https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.php#usage, just use it, no need for separate curl

Comment: Did you first create an app in vimeo and obtained the credentials - client is, client secret and token? @MLSiew

Comment: Yes Sir. I have done that step and also got my Auth token key.

Comment: Hi guys, i can run the code without error now as the edited code above. But why is it nothing is printed out? Because I would like to see the printed JSON result and get some data from the API

Comment: Hi @MLSiew you need to print your `$response` variable to see the result of your request

Comment: add `echo $response;` to print the result.

Comment: this is the result. Notice: Array to string conversion in D:\XAMPP\htdocs\MyAPI\GP.php on line 17
Array

Comment: Try print_r($response); or var_dump($response); and paste the output in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to Vimeo API for PHP. the response it's an array with have body, header and status. [Vimeo API PHP](https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.php)

[image: Response description]

to access the body. put this in your code:

```
var_dump($response['body']);
```

if you wanna print as a JSON in your page:

```
echo json_encode($response['body']);
```

I tested this script bellow in here. and it's working fine:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$client = new Vimeo("{client_id}", "{client_secret}", "{access_token}");
$video_id = "451686900";
$response = $client->request("/videos/$video_id");

print_r($response);
```

Comment: Hi friend, but for my side its still returning "The requested video couldn't be found." Even I  included the  var_dump($response['body']); it is still failed.  T.T

Comment: my video iD i was taken from the specific video URL. Btw I have included my updated code above

Comment: verify if your video in video is public or if your access token can view your private videos

Comment: i edited the answer with your credentials and a video_id from my account, and it's working.

Comment: Yes bro it works now, TQ. But it doesn't  print out the API result completely, it just printed out some of the info. And then the rest is showing this: Access forbidden!
You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 403
localhost
Apache/2.4.46 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1g PHP/7.4.9

Comment: is it because of Im using XAMPP which not support this?

Comment: add `header('Content-Type: application/json');` before the `echo` or `print_r`

Comment: thank you so much bro... u just helped me again... i do really appreciate that... hope you have a nice day:)

Comment: Any time bro 

Comment: In my case, the video was set to "hide from vimeo". I changed it to "public" and it worked.